# Google Drive from within Quartz.NET without need to re authenticate each time

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-drive-api

- .NET 4.51 using Google.Apis.* NuGet packages

I am trying to implement what is described as "offline access" in 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer.

In this scenario you have the ClientId, ClientSecret *and* the RefreshToken. Furthermore you do not want any user interaction to authorize access.

I have a job in [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) that connects to Google drive and downloads a specific file. It all works but each time I get asked to authorize the application. This is where supplying the RefreshToken would alleviate this.

However for the life of me I cannot work out how I pass in the refresh token to AuthorizeAsync().

My code is as follows:

```
private bool InternalLogin(string aClientId, string aClientSecret, string aUserName, out DriveService aGoogleDrive)
{
    //Scopes for use with the Google Drive API
    string[] scopes = Scopes.ToArray();
    aGoogleDrive = null;

    try
    {
        //Here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = aClientId,
            ClientSecret = aClientSecret
        },
            scopes,
            aUserName,
            CancellationToken.None,
            //This cannot be the FileStore it has to be something else. But what?
            new FileDataStore("MyApp.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store")
            ).Result;

        aGoogleDrive = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "MyApp Google Drive Helper",
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So can someone show me how/where to supply the RefreshToken so that when I deploy my ASP.NET WebForms application it "just works" without the need to authorize it each time with Google?

Comment: This may help (?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024120/google-drive-offline-access-using-net

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your RefreshToken to the `credentials` object that you are creating. That would result in the RefreshToken being automatically used to generate a new AccessToken:

```
var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ClientSecret
            },
            Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
    });

var credential = new UserCredential(_flow, request.UserIdentifier, new TokenResponse
    {
        AccessToken = AccessToken,
        RefreshToken = RefreshToken
    });
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        ApplicationName = "MyApp",
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        DefaultExponentialBackOffPolicy = ExponentialBackOffPolicy.Exception | ExponentialBackOffPolicy.UnsuccessfulResponse503
    });
```

Comment: Where does the value for AccessToken come from? I am also assuming request.UserIdentifier is my aUserName which is the Google Apps email address?

Comment: @TheEdge you should get Access/Refresh tokens from the OAuth flow. UserIdentifier can be any value you want (usually your app's user, to identify requests) - even NULL.

Comment: @Saguiltay My issue is that I have everything *except* the AccessToken, and don't know how to get it. Could you expand your example please?